# PySerial and Value Splitting Error

Tags: python, split, arduino, pyserial

I have encountered an error that has been seriously bothering me, and I have been unable to find a workaround. I have a python program that utilizes PySerial to import serial port values from a pulse oximeter. The problem is, when the function ser.readline() is invoked (in other words, when the python program is told to read values from the Arduino's serial monitor, the Arduino's serial values become distorted and the program returns a value unpack error.

Here is the python program.

---

```
import serial
import time 
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import csv

#time load
timestr = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")

#establish serial connection with ACM0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)

#establish variables
thymeL = [ ]
bpmL = [ ]
sp02L = [ ]
array_data = thymeL, bpmL, sp02L

#declare time
thyme = 1

#graph attributes
plt.ion()
plt.title("Pulse [BPM] & SPo2 [%] v. Time [s]", fontsize = "16")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]", fontsize = "14")
plt.ylabel("Pulse (red) [BPM] & SPo2 (blue) [%]", fontsize = "14")

while True:         
    data_in = ser.readline()
    print data_in
    data_in = data_in.strip('\n')
    bpm,sp02 = data_in.split(",") 

#convert string vals to float
    thyme = float(thyme)
    bpm = float(bpm)
    sp02 = float(sp02)

#print to terminal
    print "Time [s]: %s" % (thyme)
    print "HR [BPM]: %s" % (bpm)
    print "SPO2 [%%]: %s" % (sp02)  
    print 

#append vectors
    thymeL.append(thyme)
    bpmL.append(bpm)
    sp02L.append(sp02)

#print values to plot
    plt.scatter(thyme,bpm,color="red")
    plt.scatter(thyme,sp02,color="blue")
    plt.pause(0.1)
    time.sleep(0.05)

#update time
    thyme = thyme + 0.5

#write to .csv
    with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for t, b, s in zip(array_data[0], array_data[1], array_data[2]):
        writer.writerow([t, b, s])
```

---

The most important snippet of all is:

---

```
while True:         
    data_in = ser.readline()
    print data_in
    data_in = data_in.strip('\n')
    bpm,sp02 = data_in.split(",")
```

---

The Arduino program is as follows:

```
#include <PinChangeInt.h>
#include <eHealth.h>

int cont = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  eHealth.initPulsioximeter();

  PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, readPulsioximeter, RISING);
}

void loop() {

  char buffer[32]; // make sure buffer is large enough
  sprintf(buffer,"%d,%d \n",eHealth.getBPM(),eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());
  Serial.print(buffer);
  delay(500);

}

//=========================================================================
void readPulsioximeter(){  

  cont ++;

  if (cont == 50) { //Get only of one 50 measures to reduce the latency
    eHealth.readPulsioximeter();  
    cont = 0;
  }
}
```

So, the serial monitor is outputting values like this:

```
67,95
66,95
67,96
```

and so on.

But **only** when ser.readline() is invoked, the values become skewed and are unable to be unpacked by the split(',') function. In the following photo [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAULO.jpg) and [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExnW4.jpg), you can see the distortion of the values right when the ser.readline() is called.

How can I re-word the python OR Arduino program in such a way to circumvent this distortion and allow the values to be split and unpacked without any errors?

Comment: Do the screenshots show the result of the printing of data_in at the python end, or something else? At the Arduino end, I can't see what calls loop - I'd expect to see a while (1) loop(); somewhere.

Comment: How do you know that ser.readline() is being called when (i.e. at the instant that) the data is apparently being corrupted?

Comment: Barny, thanks for your inquiry. The screenshots are the Arduino IDE serial monitor, which I had running as I initiated the python program. Indeed, the distortions of the values in the screenshots are exactly the instance at which ser.readline() is being called. I know this because I also instructed the program to print the ser.readline() before it attempts to split it. Every time that it fails (90% of the time), it will display the very line in the serial monitor that was corrupted (and thus could not be split).

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in the Arduino end. What calls loop()?

Comment: My reasoning is that unless you have invented a telepathic Arduino, or there is something else going on that you aren't mentioning, there is no way for the Arduino to know whether or not the python script is listening. Also, if the data from the Arduino has an extra comma then of course your current code will hiccup. That hiccup is caused by the corrupted serial data, not causing the corruption.

Comment: 1) You are likely correct that simply listening in on the serial monitor of the Arduino could not cause the corruption.

2) The Arduino does not "have" an extra comma. It is programmed to output one comma between two values, then print a new line and repeat. The appearance of an extra comma is the "skipping"/corruption problem that is described. 

3) The issuance of void loop() is pretty straightforward in Arduino programs. Can you please be more specific as to what you mean by "What calls loop()?"

Comment: loop() is built-in function of the arduino and does exactly what it says -- loops consecutively. It does not need to be called.

Comment: It looks as though two things are trying to transmit from the Arduino asynchronously of each other. If loop() were being called from an interrupt routine as well as the usual Arduino call to it, that would cause intermixed data to be sent. Or is anything else in your code or the Arduino code trying to send serial data? BTW something is sending those extra characters, so 'no' is almost definitely the wrong answer to that question. Have you got any other interrupt routines active which might be doing something strange?

Answer (score 0):

So is there any possibility that something else is calling loop() asynchronously, e.g. from an interrupt routine, which might try to simultaneously transmit another string of readings at the same time as the arduino's 'mainline' calling of the loop function? An aside: if the interrupt routine readPulsioximeter() got invoked while the mainline loop() function was between the calls to eHealth.getBPM() and eHealth.getOxygenSaturation() and updated the Pulsioximeter attributes, does your code guarantee to send values from the same reading out onto the serial port?